# How to measure the amount of stack an arbitrary function call uses in C?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, callstack, stack-size

Our company bought a proprietary C function: we have a compiled library `ProcessData.a` and an interface file to call it:

```
# ProcessData.h
void ProcessData(char* pointer_to_data, int data_len);
```

We want to use this function on an `ARM` embedded CPU and we want to know how much stack space it might use.

**Question: how to measure the stack usage of an arbitrary function**?

What I tried so far is to implement the following helper functions:

```
static int* stackPointerBeforeCall;

void StartStackMeasurement(void) {
    asm ("mov %0, sp" : "=r"(stackPointerBeforeCall));
    // For some reason I can't overwrite values immediately below the
    // stack pointer. I suspect a return address is placed there.
    static int* pointer;
    pointer = stackPointerBeforeCall - 4;
    // Filling all unused stack space with a fixed constant
    while (pointer != &_sstack) {
        *pointer = 0xEEEEEEEE;
        pointer--;
    }
    *pointer = 0xEEEEEEEE;
}

void FinishStackMeasurement(void) {
    int* lastUnusedAddress = &_sstack;
    while (*lastUnusedAddress == 0xEEEEEEEE) {
        lastUnusedAddress++;
    }
    // Printing how many stack bytes a function has used
    printf("STACK: %d\n", (stackPointerBeforeCall-lastUnusedAddress)*sizeof(int));
}
```

And then use them just before and after the function call:

```
StartStackMeasurement();
ProcessData(array, sizeof(array));
FinishStackMeasurement();
```

But this seems like a dangerous hack - especially the part where I am subtracting `4` from the `stackPointerBeforeCall` and overwriting everything below. Is there a better way?

Comment: There's no _good_ way to do this, but there might be a less hacky way. Does the embedded environment where you're running this code have memory protection? Does it have threads? Does it have the (deprecated, but unreplaceable) POSIX functions `getcontext`, `makecontext`, `setcontext`, and `swapcontext`?

Comment: Filling the stack with a pattern and checking it afterwards is a normal approach for stack checking. If the stack pointer always points to the value pushed last, then subtracting 4 is correct for a 32-bit system. (I didn't check the documentation for ARM.) Without knowing details about your OS and/or available libraries we don't know if there are any special mechanisms for stack checking on your system. You might have to perform the test with different input data in case the stack usage depends on the data. Consider asking the creator of the library about the maximum stack usage.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to ask the vendor.

Comment: @zwol the environment does not have threads. We run a full system on the embedded platform (no distinction between OS and user space), so the only sort of memory protection is a hard fault if you try to write to an address below `_sstack`, but apart from that, no. You can read and write to each valid RAM address at any place in the code. No POSIX functions described (there is no OS, i.e. the "OS" is our program that is being run on the device")

Comment: One very hacky way is to read the sp through assembler, full everything from sp to the end of the stack with a known hex sequence, 0xAA or such. Then check how many 0xAA the function changed. Not an exact science, but a good old trick used to determining peak stack use in bare metal systems.

Comment: @Lundin so basically, what's done in the question?

Comment: I guess, if you you can assume that stack frames are always 32 bit aligned, with padding. But well, if you have the code, simply single step through the function and watch the SP?

Comment: Btw the posted code needs to ensure that `pointer` isn't allocated on the stack or it might decide to destroy itself and replace the contents with address 0xEEEEEEEE :) Best fix for that is `static int* pointer; pointer = stackPointerBeforeCall - 4;`

Comment: @Lundin nice catch! I guess the program did not crash in my case because `pointer` was stored in a register?

Comment: Chances are good that even the vendor doesn't know it unless the function is written in assembly. Why don't you try to analyze the disassembly? That's the only way to find it out for certain.

Comment: @mercury0114 Likely in an index/address register, yes. But there are no guarantees that it will end up there. Generally, manipulating the stack manually from C is very dangerous. Tends to destroy both local variables and function return address/stacked registers as per calling convention.

Answer (score 5):

Compile the program and analyze the assembly or machine code for the function in question.  Many functions use the stack in a static manner, and this static size can be reasoned by analysis of the compiled code.  Some functions dynamically allocate stack space based on some computation, usually associated with some input parameter.  In those cases, you'll see different instructions being used to allocate stack space, and will have to work back to reason how the dynamic stack size might be derived.

Of course, this analysis would have to be redone with updates to the function (library).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getrusage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) which is a function that gets you the resource usage of your software, in particular `ru_isrss` which is

> An integral value expressed the same way, which is the amount of unshared memory used for stack space

[(source)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Resource-Usage.html)

You can then compare it to the stack usage of your program with a mocked call to the library.

However, this will only work if your system has implemented `ru_isrss` (unlike linux), otherwise the field will be set to 0.